# Cyclic Decomposition of Torsion Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $T:M\rightarrow M$ be a linear map given by,
$T =
\left[
\begin{array}{c c c}
1 & -1 & 5\\
2 & 0 & 13\\
0 & -3 & 2
\end{array}
\right]
$. Think of $M$ as a $R[X]$ module where $X$ acts on $M$ by $T$. Show that 
(i) $M$ is a torsion module. 
(ii) Decompose $M$ as a direct sum of cyclic modules.

I have got the 1st part. I will define the map $f:R[X] \times M\rightarrow M$ by $f(P,V)=P(T).V$. This shows that $M$ is a module. Then taking the characteristic polynomial of $T$ as $P$, we have that $P(T).V=0$ for all $V\in M$. But I am not getting how to approach the 2nd part of the problem. Please help!!

Comment: Are you sure that matrix is correct ? The characteristic poly does not factor nicely.

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve the characteristic equation but it is not in good form. What is the procedure of this cyclic decomposition in general?